# Why can't I stop replaykit live broadcast in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get this error when I press the stop button to end the broadcast.
It was working perfectly an hour ago but now I get this error in the console and it doesn't stop the broadcast either.
What am I doing wrong?

> [UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on
>   UIWindow:  0x129e0d800; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H;
>   gestureRecognizers = NSArray: 0x1702424c0>; layer = UIWindowLayer:
>   0x17002d140>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation.
>   Ignoring.

```
if node.name == "stoplive" {
    self.broadcastController?.finishBroadcast { error in 
        if error == nil {
            stopButton.removeFromParent 
            addGoLiveButton()
            print("stop broadcast")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the block is not called on the main thread. Try wrapping your view mutations in DispatchQueue.main.async.

Comment: still getting the same error in the console

Comment: it works now after i cleaned the project but is it possible that error will come back?

Answer (score 0):

you cant stop the live broadcast normally else you can force quit the broadcast with a in build protocol

**func finishBroadcastWithError(_ error: Error)**

for more you can refer [apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler/2721526-finishbroadcastwitherror)

you can use in in sampleHandler on RPBroadcast protocol

let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "You have Stopped Screen Sharing"]
finishBroadcastWithError(NSError(domain: "ScreenShare", code: -1, userInfo: userInfo))